# Focus on Keylistener

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, keylistener, setfocus

So what I've got is that I would love to try and make an little login applet. I'm using Java Windowsbuilder for it, to make it easyer for me. I hope the code isn't to messy, because I'm just a starter.

The problem I've got is that My JButton "login" only registers a keyevent when it's selected trought tab, or when you first click it. What I want is that I can use the button always just by pressing the "ENTER" key.

Hope you guys solve my problem :)

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JButton;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import org.eclipse.wb.swing.FocusTraversalOnArray;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;

public class nummer1 extends JFrame{

private JPanel contentPane;
public static nummer1 theFrame;
private JTextField textFieldUsername;
private JTextField textFieldPass;
private nummer1  me;
private JLabel lblCheck;
private String password = "test", username = "test";

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                nummer1 frame = new nummer1();
                nummer1.theFrame = frame;
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
public void Check(){
    String Pass = textFieldPass.getText();
    String Username = textFieldUsername.getText();

    System.out.println(Pass);

    if (Pass.equals(password) && Username.equals(username)){

        lblCheck.setText("Correct Login");

    }else{

        lblCheck.setText("Invalid username or password");

    }
}



/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public nummer1() {
    me = this;

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 356, 129);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);


    JLabel lblUsername = new JLabel("Username:");
    lblUsername.setBounds(10, 11, 61, 14);
    contentPane.add(lblUsername);

    JLabel lblPassword = new JLabel("Password:");
    lblPassword.setBounds(10, 36, 61, 14);
    contentPane.add(lblPassword);

    textFieldUsername = new JTextField();
    textFieldUsername.setBounds(81, 8, 107, 20);
    contentPane.add(textFieldUsername);
    textFieldUsername.setColumns(10);
    me.textFieldUsername = textFieldUsername;

    textFieldPass = new JTextField();
    textFieldPass.setBounds(81, 33, 107, 20);
    contentPane.add(textFieldPass);
    textFieldPass.setColumns(10);
    me.textFieldPass = textFieldPass;

    JButton btnLogin = new JButton("Login");
    contentPane.requestFocusInWindow();
    btnLogin.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
                me.Check();
                System.out.println("hi");
            }
        }
    });

    btnLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            me.Check();
        }
    });
    btnLogin.setBounds(198, 7, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnLogin);

    JLabel lblCheck = new JLabel("");
    lblCheck.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.TRAILING);
    lblCheck.setBounds(10, 65, 264, 14);
    contentPane.add(lblCheck);
    me.lblCheck = lblCheck;
    contentPane.setFocusTraversalPolicy(new FocusTraversalOnArray(new         
            Component[]{lblUsername, lblPassword, textFieldUsername, textFieldPass,   btnLogin, lblCheck}));

}
}
```

Thanks Emil!

Answer (score 2):

> What I want is that I can use the button always just by pressing the "ENTER" key

Sounds like you want to make the "login" button the default button for the dialog.

See [Enter Key and Button](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/25/enter-key-and-button/) for the problem and solution.

Answer (score 0):

When using panels KeyListeners won't work unless the panel is focusable. What you can do is make a KeyBinding to the ENTER key using the InputMap and ActionMap for your panel.

```
public class Sample extends JPanel{
    //Code
    Sample() {
          //More code
          this.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke((char)KeyEvent.VK_ENTER), "Enter" );
          this.getActionMap().put("Enter", new EnterAction());
    }
    private class EnterAction extends AbstractAction(){
        @Override
        public void ActionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            //Acion
        }
    }
}
```